# createWriteStream vs writeFile?

Tags: node.js, file-io, stream, request, fwrite

What is the basic difference between these two operations ?

```
someReadStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.png'));
```

vs

```
someReadStream.on('data', function(chunk) { blob += chunk } );
someReadStream.on('end', function() { fs.writeFile('foo.png', blob) });
```

When using request library for scraping, I can save pics (png, bmp) etc.. only with the former method and with the latter one there is same gibbersh (binary) data but image doesn't render.

How are they different ?

Comment: Are you sure that `chunk`s aren't buffers? Buffers concatenation isn't that simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are working with streams in node.js you should prefer to pipe them.

According to [Node.js’s stream-event docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data), `data` events emit either buffers (by default) or strings (if `encoding` was set).

When you are working with text streams you can use `data` events to concatenate chunks of string data together. Then you'll be able to work with your data as one string.

But when working with binary data it's not so simple, because you'll receive buffers. To concatenate buffers you use special methods like [`Buffer.concat`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength). It's possible to use a similar approach for binary streams:

```
var buffers = [];
readstrm.on('data', function(chunk) {
    buffers.push(chunk);
});
readstrm.on('end', function() {
    fs.writeFile('foo.png', Buffer.concat(buffers));
});
```

You can notice when something goes wrong by checking the output file's size.

Comment: thanks that was eyeopening for me but i cant achieve it the 'hard way' too! .
var buffers = [];

readstrm.on('data', function(chunk) {
   var blob = new Buffer(chunk.length);
   buffers.push(blob);
});

readstrm.on('end', function() {
 var finalblob = Buffer.concat(buffers);
 fs.writeFile('img.bmp', finalblob);
});

Comment: I did it once and it worked... There was no `concat` in node 0.6.x though, so I used some node module from github.

Comment: I updated my answer, but my code looks pretty much like yours.