# Blurring image with canvas nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

It seems like `ctx.filter = "blur(amount)"` doesn't work. Here's my code:

```js
const {
    body
} = await request.get(
    url
);
const data = await Canvas.loadImage(body);
ctx.filter = "blur(50px)"
ctx.drawImage(data, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.heigth)
const final = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
    canvas.toBuffer(),
    "blurred.png"
);
```

Yeah it's for Discord.

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't work" ? Regardless, I don't believe you can use canvas within nodejs directly. Canvases are DOM thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137936/can-i-let-node-js-generate-a-canvas-without-an-html-page

Answer (score 1):

Indeed they still don't support this feature.
[Here is the issue tracking the feature request.](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1063)

Apparently, these filters are not built-in Cairo, the rendering engine used by node-canvas, however Skia, an other rendering engine that node-canvas could switch to in the near future apparently does. So there is hope it comes one day, but for the time being, we have to implement it ourselves.

For gaussian blur, you can look at the [StackBlur.js](https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur) project, which was the de-facto blur filter library before browsers implement it natively. Here is a [glitch project](https://node-canvas-gaussianblur.glitch.me/) as an example.