# Sending image as binary via require("http") request to a remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-request

I'm trying to send an image to remote server from nodejs server. Here's the request format so far.

**Note:** Just like binary request in postman and choosing a file and sending)

```
function upload(options, body) {
    body = body || '';
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const https = require('https');
        https.request(options, function(response) {
            var body = [];
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            response.on('end', function(){
                resolve(JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString()))
            });
        }).on('error', function(error) {
            reject(error);
        }).end(body);
    });
}
```

---

**Use:**

```
var options = {
    hostname: "hostname",
    path: "/upload",
    port: 443,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    }
};

fs.readFile('./img/thumbnail.png', function(error, data) {
     options.body = data;
     upload(options).then(...
});
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

After several attempts, came across an efficient strategy to upload images via streams, here's how it looks like but still not success.

```
const https = require('https');
var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
    var buffers = [];
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffers.push(chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
        var body = JSON.parse(buffers.length ? Buffer.concat(buffers).toString() : '""');
        response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 ? resolve(body) : reject(body);
    });
}).on('error', function(error) {
    reject(error);
});

const fs = require('fs');
var readStream = fs.ReadStream(body.path);
readStream.pipe(request);
readStream.on('close', function(){
    request.end();
});
```

[Reference](https://debugmode.net/2014/01/14/how-to-upload-file-in-node-js/)

Comment: `uploadImage(options, body)` doesn't look right... where is `body` defined?

Comment: sorry i fixed the typos, I'm confused about where to pass the image data to???

Comment: Have you looked at [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js/12999483#12999483) on this site, there are many examples of how to send data with Node, and most would probably recomend using the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) middleware.

Comment: I've looked up so much, already spent hours, desperate in need of help, and can't use the Request, it has to be low level nodejs code.

Comment: All I want is how can I send the binary data in node.js just like in postman's option. I've edited with a screenshot now

Comment: Looks like you're already doing it, the data is in `options.body` and is sent to the remote server with that key

Comment: @adeneo so for the sake of understanding and in context of my postman screenshot, `binary` -> `options.body` and for `raw`, `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `form-data` -> will go to body, please confirm or correct.

Comment: still having issues, no `on('data')` or `on('end')` is getting called when I pass the image body in `response.end(body)` function, any advice guys?

Comment: "But still not success" is not a description of a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd say the remote server end is unable to receive my file, the code is working now though. so not sure if I'm sending the file property, Read Stream correctly reads my image, is Edit 2 correct in your opinion?

Comment: @user2727195 I think that code is fine. I'm still not sure if you're having trouble or not.

Comment: From the remote server's response headers content-type I see this value, `application/octet-stream`, maybe the remote server expects octet-stream, not sure how I can specify this while sending the image data

Comment: I think I'm reaching the problem, there was an issue with the image, I selected another one now and guess what, `readStream('close'` is not getting called, it's a 3.1 MB image

Comment: damn it's the timeout of mocha exiting from tests early, I've increased the timeout and works now, but nevertheless most importantly I learned how to send images via readStreams

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want this:

```
fs.createReadStream('./img/thumbnail.png').pipe(https.request({
  hostname: 'hostname',
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'image/png',
  }
}, function (response) { ... }));
```

The issue with your code is that you were putting the body into `options.body`, but per [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback), it doesn't look like there is any such option.

Comment: so all options from screenshot in my question, whether `binary`, `raw`, `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `form-data`, they all go into `body`, how to you specify `Content-Type` for each?

Comment: I don't know what Postman means by those various things. In particular, I can't think of what "binary" versus "raw" might mean. `x-www-form-urlencoded` is presumably exactly that `Content-Type` (and formatting of the body), and `form-data` is probably `multipart/form-data`. You can easily look both of those up.

Comment: Hi @smarx, guess what, I don't get any response in `response.on('end', function(){` when I pass the image data directly into `end()` function, not even on `response.on('data')`, it's like everything freezes, is there something wrong with the way I'm reading image data and passing on?

Comment: When you say you "don't get any response," do you mean that your handler is not called for those events?

Comment: I've added another piece of code in the edit section, please review.

Comment: [You shouldn't be using `readFile` in this situation.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15007987/201952)

Comment: @josh3736 smarx please review my Edit2 in my question