# createReadStream not working/extremely slow for large files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dropbox-api

Im using DropBox API to upload files. To upload the files to dropbox I am going through the following steps:

1. First upload file from `form` to a local directory on the server.
2. Read File from local directory using `fs.createReadStream`
3. Send file to Dropbox via the dropbox API.

**The issue:**

For some reason `fs.createReadStream` takes absolute ages when reading and uploading a large file. Now the file I'm trying to upload is only **12MB** which is not a big file and **it takes approximately 18mins to upload/process a 12MB file**.

**I don't know where the issue is either it's in `createReadStream` or dropbox api code.**

It works with files of size within `kb`.

**My Code:**

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN HERE',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg': "{\"path\": \"/test/" + req.file.originalname + "\",\"mode\": \"overwrite\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }, 

      // I think the issue is here.
      body: fs.createReadStream(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`)
};

 rp(options)
    .then(() => {
        return _deleteLocalFile(req.file.originalname)
    })
    .then(() => {
        return _generateShareableLink(req.file.originalname)
    })
    .then((shareableLink) => {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, shareableLink)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err)
    });
```

**Update:**

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
```

Comment: what is rp ? the problem is probably more how it handles streams rather than the stream itself

Comment: @laurent thank you for the comment. I've updated my code which explains what rp is. Basically its a `request` promise library. I've been trying to fix this for days. It seems crazy that it takes **18mins** to upload a **12mb** file.

Comment: If you wish to stream the request documentation advises to directly pipe: 
fs.createReadStream('file.json').pipe(request.post('targetSite',optionsAndHeaders)). However there are more "modern" http client nodejs libraries.

Comment: Actually you even have a DropBox sdk with an upload example https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/node/upload.js

Comment: Try watching memory usage of the node process while it's running. Perhaps there's a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: You can always compare your time result with upload feature available in official Dropbox web-app.

Answer (score 3):

I had an experience similar to this issue before and after a large amount of head scratching and digging around, I was able to resolve the issue, in my case anyway.

For me, the issue arose due to the default chunking size for createReadStream() being quite small 64kb and this for some reason having a knock on effect when uploading to Dropbox.

The solution therefore was to increase the chunk size.

```
// Try using chunks of 256kb
body: fs.createReadStream(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`, {highWaterMark : 256 * 1024});
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/request/request#streaming

I believe you need to pipe the stream to the request.

see this answer:
 [Sending large image data over HTTP in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001822/sending-large-image-data-over-http-in-node-js)