# Panorama Image Loading is very slow

Tags: javascript, panoramas

My requirement is to load panorama image which I am receiving from an API using CURL. It is taking more time to load and showing black screen till it is fully loaded. I tried to convert the image into base64 but the conversion itself taking longer time. Any help?

Comment: Please, rephrase your question. What is the expected result vs actual? What have your tried so far?

Comment: Hi Alexander, Actually I have to load one panoramic image which is not on my machine but have to fetch from another server using CURL method. The image loading is taking around 1 min to load which is not acceptable as per customer experience. I tried to convert the image to base64 but the conversion is also taking that much of time.

Comment: Well, the issue with your question is that it is impossible to say how you serve your image file. Are you using nodejs? If yes, you should look into streams. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001822/sending-large-image-data-over-http-in-node-js